# Can't apply lodash partial to function created with bluebird promisifyAll

Tags: javascript, function, lodash, bluebird

The below code takes a all the methods in object `lib` and promisify's them. Then I can use the callback style function as a promise, which works. Then I use `_.partial` provide the function and arguments, this returns a function. When I call that function it throws an error instead of wrapping the function. I have a whole bunch of tests [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1369) that show that this behavior only happens to functions generated with `promisifyAll`. What's the problem here and how can it be fixed?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var _ = require("lodash")

var lib = {}

lib.dummy = function(path, encoding, cb){
  return cb(null, "file content here")
}

Promise.promisifyAll(lib)

lib.dummyAsync("path/hello.txt", "utf8").then(function(text){
  console.log(text) // => "file content here"
})

var readFile = _.partial(lib.dummyAsync, "path/hello.txt", "utf8")

readFile() // throws error
```

It's throwing

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at tryCatcher (/Users/thomas/Desktop/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:22)
    at ret (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/thomas/Desktop/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promisify.js:163:12), <anonymous>:11:39)
    at wrapper (/Users/thomas/Desktop/project/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomas/Desktop/project/issue.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:426:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:444:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:306:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:946:3
```

Whereas this works perfectly fine.

```
var dummyPromise = function(path, encoding){
  return Promise.resolve("file content here")
}

var readFile = _.partial(dummyPromise, "path/hello.txt", "utf8")

readFile().then(function(text){
  console.log(text) // => "file content here"
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying answer [from the issue tracker](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/714#issuecomment-125016855):

The problem is `_.partial` does not maintain the `this` value which is required when you `promisifyAll`. You can either use `promisify` instead or you can use `_.bind` which is the appropriate lodash method.

```
var o = {};
o.dummy = function(path, encoding, cb){
  return cb(null, "file content here " + path + " " +encoding);
}

Promise.promisifyAll(o);

o.dummyAsync("a","b").then(function(data){
   console.log("HI", data); 
});

// and not `_.partial`
var part = _.bind(o.dummyAsync, o, "a1", "b2");
part().then(function(data){
   console.log("Hi2", data); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hczmb2kx/

Comment: Any idea why I can't pass a bound function into then? https://gist.github.com/reggi/0b60d07300b348a6365e

Answer (score 1):

`promisifyAll` does create methods that expect to be called on the original instance (as it does invoke the original `.dummy` method), but `partial` does not bind the functions you pass in, so you are getting a `this` error. You can use either `readFile.call(lib)` or `_.partial(lib.dummyAsync.bind(lib), …)` or just `lib.dummyAsync.bind(lib, …)`.