# Writing promises without opening then calls

Tags: javascript, function, promise, lodash, bluebird

In an effort to stop writing a lot of duplicate code I'm trying to not open then calls. I'd preferably only like to pass functions around from a top level. Like this.

```
function ensureLink(srcPath, dstPath){
  dstPath = fsRedux.predictDir(srcPath, dstPath)
  var dstDir = path.dirname(dstPath)
  return fsRedux.exists(dstPath)
    .then(_.partialRight(fsRedux.ifFalseThrow, false, new Error(dstPath+" exists cannot ensure link")))
    .then(_.bind(fsExtra.mkdirsAsync, fsExtra, dstDir))
    .then(_.bind(_.bind(fsExtra.linkAsync, fsExtra, srcPath, dstPath)))
}
```

However the above code doesn't work. The test below shows that you cant pass a `bound` `promisifyAll` async function. The reason is that the then value is passed into these promises which causes them to act as the next argument in the call, for these functions that means they fire as a callback, which is why the first test error's out with `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.` in mocha.

```
var chai = require("chai")
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised")
chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
chai.should()

var path = require("path")
var _ = require("lodash")
var mock = require("mock-fs")

var Promise = require("bluebird")
var fsRedux = require("./fs-redux")
var fsExtra = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs-extra"))
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"))

mock({
  'path/hello-alpha.txt': 'file content here',
  'path/hello-beta.txt': 'file content here'
})

var dstPath = "path/to/fake/dir/"

function closedThen(srcPath, dstPath){
  dstPath = fsRedux.predictDir(srcPath, dstPath)
  var dstDir = path.dirname(dstPath)
  return fsRedux.exists(dstPath)
    .then(_.partialRight(fsRedux.ifFalseThrow, false, new Error(dstPath+" exists cannot ensure link")))
    .then(_.bind(fsExtra.mkdirsAsync, fsExtra, dstDir))
    .then(_.bind(_.bind(fsExtra.linkAsync, fsExtra, srcPath, dstPath)))
}

function openThen(srcPath, dstPath){
  dstPath = fsRedux.predictDir(srcPath, dstPath)
  var dstDir = path.dirname(dstPath)
  return fsRedux.exists(dstPath)
    .then(_.partialRight(fsRedux.ifFalseThrow, false, new Error(dstPath+" exists cannot ensure link")))
    .then(function(){
      return _.bind(fsExtra.mkdirsAsync, fsExtra, dstDir)()
    })
    .then(function(){
      return _.bind(fsExtra.linkAsync, fsExtra, srcPath, dstPath)()
    })
}

describe("issue", function(){
  describe("closedThen()", function(){
    it("should return then and run promise", function(){
      return closedThen("path/hello-alpha.txt", dstPath).then(function(){
        return fsExtra.readFileAsync("path/to/fake/dir/hello-alpha.txt", "utf8").should.eventually.equal("file content here")
      })
    })
  })
  describe("openThen()", function(){
    it("should return then and run promise", function(){
      return openThen("path/hello-beta.txt", dstPath).then(function(){
        return fsExtra.readFileAsync("path/to/fake/dir/hello-beta.txt", "utf8").should.eventually.equal("file content here")
      })
    })
  })
})
```

What functions exist, or way of wrapping the bound function would allow for working with promises this way?

Update:

I'm looking for a library of suite of function wrappers (lodash has a bunch of them) that allow for an easy interface of [partialing](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) or [binding from my question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639639/cant-apply-lodash-partial-to-function-created-with-bluebird-promisifyall) or wrapping functions to pass to a `then` or run within a `Promise.reduce`. That way chaining promises are really easy.

Ideally I just want to know how to get the line working, a way of wrapping it so that when it's passed a result from the then it ignores it. Or a recommended alternative.

```
.then(_.bind(fsExtra.mkdirsAsync, fsExtra, dstDir))
```

Comment: Really hard to understand exactly what you're asking - can you clarify further.  A promisified function (somewhat by definition) returns a promise and no longer uses a callback.  If you call it, it will return a promise that is resolved only when the underlying async operation is done.  In addition, if you want serial operation, not parallel operation, you need to pass a function reference to a `.then()` handler, not the return value of executing some function (unless that return value is itself a function that is what you want called in sequence).

Comment: Alas, editing didn't help much in understanding the problem. There is a bunch of different problems descriptions mixed up. I see at least 1. unit test is not properly built and it results in a time out (not a failed assertion) 2. misunderstanding how `bind` works. actually for example last `then` handler `_.bind(fsExtra.linkAsync...` receives result of previous promise in chain. But `fsExtra.linkAsync` gets it as a third parameter (after `dstPath`)

Comment: I still don't follow.  Maybe you can just back up and describe a specific sequence of operations you want to script and then ask how's the most efficient way to write that?  It sounds like you're trying to ask some sort of generic question, but using a really complicated set of code with lots of issues to try to describe the problem and you're losing us in that complexity.  Can you reduce the problem to a much simpler example?

Comment: what are fsRedux, fsExtra.mkdirsAsync, fsExtra and others?

Comment: @webduvet `fsRedux` is a personal module the methods named are pretty self explanitory. and `fsExtra` is the `fs-extra` node module wrapped with bluebird's `promisifyAll()`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Seems like you're exerting a lot of effort to make your code un-debuggable. Eliminating the anonymous functions typically passed to .then() means you have nowhere to put break points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using [`Ramda`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda).

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var R = require("ramda")
var path = require("path")
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"))
var fse = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs-extra"))

function ifThrow(value, desiredValue, error){
  if(value == desiredValue) throw error
  return value
}

var fsEnsureLink = function(srcpath, dstpath){
  return R.pipeP.apply(null, [
    R.always(fs.lstatAsync(srcpath).then(R.T, R.F)),
    R.partialRight(ifThrow, false, new Error("source path does not exist")),
    R.always(fs.lstatAsync(dstpath).then(R.T, R.F)),
    R.partialRight(ifThrow, true, new Error("destination path exists")),
    R.always(fse.mkdirsAsync(path.dirname(dstpath))),
    R.always(fs.linkAsync(srcpath, dstpath)),
    R.T,
  ])()
}

fsEnsureLink("./package.json", "./test/package.json")
// promise -> true || Error thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three functions that allow you to only have to ever write one-method deep promises. They use the module [`dotty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotty) to edit an object set to a global scope outside the promise chain.

With `wrap` you can ignore the current then value in the chain.

```
function wrap(fn){
  return function(){
    return fn()
  }
}
```

With `exportResult` you can store the value for later use.

```
function exportResult(obj, property){
  return function(value){
    dotty.put(obj, property, value)
    return value
  }
}
```

With `provideResult` you can return a previous result value to return to the next `then` call.

```
function provideResult(obj, property){
  return function(){
    return dotty.get(obj, property)
  }
}
```

Resulting in something like this.

```
function ensureLink(srcPath, dstPath){
  dstPath = fsRedux.predictDir(srcPath, dstPath)
  var dstDir = path.dirname(dstPath)
  var values = {}
  return fsRedux.exists(dstPath)
    .then(exportResult(values, "exists"))
    .then(_.partialRight(fsRedux.ifFalseThrow, false, new Error(dstPath+" exists cannot ensure link")))
    .then(wrap(_.bind(fsExtra.mkdirsAsync, fsExtra, dstDir)))
    .then(wrap(_.bind(fsExtra.linkAsync, fsExtra, srcPath, dstPath)))
    .then(provideResult(values, "exists"))
    // continue the chain provide result from exists...
}
```

I originally was looking for a more elegant solution to this. Or recommendations on a current standard that does this.

Comment: I'm finding Ramda really interesting but not so helpfull when it comes to helping create complex promise chains and managing control flow.

Comment: Did you have a look at `curryN`, `composeP`? Also your `wrap` could be done using `nAry`.

Comment: Took a closer look at Ramda and posted an answer above using it. I'd appreciate your thoughts and I'd love a replacement or library for the `ifThrow` function.

Comment: Given that you're always using it together with that `.then(R.T, R.F)`, I'd just have used `.then(R.T, R.always(Promise.reject(new Error(…))))`. Or just Bluebirds `.catchThrow(…)`.